# Trying to create a web service

Tags: java

I have create a method to be turned into a web service which looks like this:

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "doCanny")
public void doCanny()
{
    try 
    {
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat color = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\bheda\\Desktop\\Cat03.jpg");


    Mat gray = new Mat();
    Mat draw = new Mat();
    Mat wide = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(color, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.Canny(gray, wide, 50, 150, 3, false);
    wide.convertTo(draw, CvType.CV_8U);

    if(Imgcodecs.imwrite("C:\\Users\\bheda\\Desktop\\Cat03.jpg", draw))
    {
        System.out.println("edge is detected .......");
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

When I deploy and test this web service I get the following error:

> WS00041: Service invocation threw an exception with message : null;
>   Refer to the server log for more details Exceptions details :
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:342)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.invoke(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:106)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.JAXWSServlet.doPost(JAXWSServlet.java:157)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>   at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>   at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.monitoring.WebServiceTesterServlet.doPost(WebServiceTesterServlet.java:313)
>   ... 32 more Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.fault.ServerSOAPFaultException:
>   Client received SOAP Fault from server: no opencv_java340 in
>   java.library.path Please see the server log to find more detail
>   regarding exact cause of the failure. at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:193)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:131)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:253)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:203)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:290)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:119)
>   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:92)
>   at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:161) at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy313.doCanny(Unknown Source) ... 37 more

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I thought it could be my file path but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
no opencv_java340 in java.library.path
```

That's what threw the error. `Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME` points to the OpenCV native libraries (DLL files on Windows, so files on Linux). When you start up Glassfish, you have to add the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and set it to the path of your OpenCV installation.

Comment: I am using netbeans and had already added -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\bheda\Desktop\opencv\build\java\x64" to the vm options.  How do I add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in Windows?